# Accessing list from method in another method

Tags: c#, list

I would like to access list (in my program named "section") inside a method(menu choose). I tried 3 ways:

```
public static void dataBase()
        {
                List<float> section = new List<float>();
        }


// 1st try
//  List<float> section = new List<float>();
//
        public static void mainMenu()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Trans->Connector->\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Add: \n1. Section \n2. Wled \n3. Regenerator");
            menuChoose();
        }

        public static void menuChoose()
        {

            var key = Console.ReadKey();
            switch (key.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.D1:
                case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:

                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Give lenght:");
                    float result;
                    float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);
                    dataBase.section.Add();
                    section.Add(result);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.D2:

                    Console.WriteLine("2");
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.D3:
                    Console.WriteLine("3");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("default");
                    break;
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int WeldCount;
            int ConnectroCount;
//3rd try
// List<float> section = new List<float>();
//

            mainMenu();
        }
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you please state your question and try to minimize the code to show your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a member in the local scope of your function outside it. You might want to think about making it a private instance variable inside your class that you will then be able to access from any method declared that belongs to this class, something along these lines:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // this field is accessible from any method declared within this class
    private List<Float> section;
    public MyClass()
    {
        section = new List<Float>();
    }

    private void someMethod()
    {
        section.Add(2.2);    
        Console.WriteLine(section[0]); // example 
    }
}
```

Comment: I made my class public as you did. I made a constructor as you did with 'section = new List<Float>();' and got error Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: I have to see more of the code you executed in order to help you... Edit your question with all the details please

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make it class level variable (like in your 1st try) and make it static.

However you should use return value from your `menuChoose()` method. Having all code depend on single static list instance is not ideal.

```
public static List<float> menuChoose()
        {

            List<float> selection = new List<float>();
            var key = Console.ReadKey();
            switch (key.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.D1:
                case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:

                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Give lenght:");
                    float result;
                    float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);
                    selection.Add(result);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.D2:

                    Console.WriteLine("2");
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.D3:
                    Console.WriteLine("3");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("default");
                    break;
            }
          return selection;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to it, if you would implement something like this:

```
public static class DataBase
{
    public static List<float> Section { get; set; }

    static DataBase()
    {
        Section = new List<float>();
    }
}
```

here how to use e.g. in your switch statement:

```
    case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:
         Console.Clear();
         Console.WriteLine("Give lenght:");
         float result;
         float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);
         DataBase.Section.Add(result);
      break;
```

I didn't get what you try to achieve by `dataBase.section.Add();` so I removed it in my example.

Comment: It do not work in my switch statement. I made static void DataBase().

Comment: Please see my Edit. You are able to work with the static list without adding a method to the class. List property already offers possibility to add values to it.

Answer (score 0):

I could not use any of your answers so I did this in my way(much worse than yours, for sure)

```
public class Program
{

    public int WeldCount;
    public int ConnectroCount;
    public List<float> section = new List<float>();
    //public List<> TrackElements = new List<>();

    public Program()
    {
        section.Add(0);

    }
    public void showResults()
    {
        float allSections = 0;
        foreach (float item in section)
        {
            allSections += item;
        }

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("c1 {0}, c2 {1}, c3{2}", WeldCount,ConnectroCount,allSections);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }



    public void finalConstruction()
    {




    }


    public static void mainMenu()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Add: \n1. Section \n2. Weld \n3. Regenerator\n4. Show results");




    }


    public void menuChoose()
    {

        var key = Console.ReadKey();

        switch (key.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.D1:
            case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Give lenght:");
                float result;
                float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);


                section.Add(result);



                mainMenu();
                menuChoose();

                break;

            case ConsoleKey.D2:

                WeldCount++;
                mainMenu();
                menuChoose();
                break;

            case ConsoleKey.D3:
                ConnectroCount++;
                mainMenu();
                menuChoose();
                break;

            case ConsoleKey.D4:
                showResults();
                mainMenu();
                menuChoose();
                break;





            default:
                Console.WriteLine("wtf did just happend");
                break;
        }

    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Program program = new Program();
        mainMenu();
        program.menuChoose();




    }





}
}
```